# Updated Stripe integration with MERN shopping app

Tags: reactjs, api, stripe-payments, mern, stripes

I want to integrate my old legacy version of stripe which is not working now to the new updated with 3D secure way.
How should I change this code, I tried to search through YT and blogs but found none

my cart: Where a token is created which is then sent to the backend for further processing of the payment.

```
 const onToken = (token) =>{
     setStripeToken(token); 
   }
    // const history = useNavigate();
    const navigate = useNavigate();


    //token returns on successful order placing
    // console.log(stripeToken); 

    useEffect(() => {
        const makeRequest = async () => {
          try {
            const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
              tokenId: stripeToken.id,
              amount: cart.total,
            });

            navigate("/success", {state:res});
          } 
          catch(err)
          {
              console.log(err);
          }
        };
        stripeToken && makeRequest();
      }, [stripeToken, cart.total , navigate]);

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar data={searchLinks}/>
            <Announcement/>
        
                <Wrapper>
                    <Title>YOUR CART</Title>
                    <Top>
                        <Link to="/products"><TopBotton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopBotton></Link>
                        {/* <a href="/products"><TopBotton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopBotton></a> */}
                        
                        <TopTexts>
                            <TopText><ShoppingBag style={{margin:"-3px 2px", color: "teal"}}/> BAG({cart.quantity})</TopText>
                            <TopText><Favorite style={{margin:"-3px 2px", color: "red"}}/> WISHLIST(0)</TopText>
                        </TopTexts>
                           <StripeCheckout
                                name="Ecofelx"
                                image="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/Ardent10"
                                billingAddress
                                shippingAddress
                                description={`Your total is ₹ ${cart.total}`}
                                currency="INR"
                                amount={cart.total*100}
                                token={onToken}
                                stripeKey={KEY}>
                                <TopBotton type="filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopBotton>
                            </StripeCheckout>
                    </Top>
                    <Bottom>
                    
                        {cart.products.length=== 0? 

                          (
                            <Info>
                                <h2>Your Cart is Empty</h2> 
                                <EmptyImage src='https://cdni.iconscout.com/illustration/premium/thumb/empty-cart-2130356-1800917.png' alt=''/>
                            </Info>
                          ) :(
                              
                            <Info>
                            
                            {cart.products.map((product)=>(
                                <Product key={product._id}>
                                    <ProductDetail>
                                        <Image src={product.img}/>
                                        <Details>
                                            <ProductName><b>Product:</b> {product.title}</ProductName>
                                            <ProductId><b>ID:</b> {product._id}</ProductId>
                                            <ProductId><b>Color:</b> <ProductColor color={product.color}/></ProductId>                                          
                                            <ProductSize><b>Size:</b> {product.size}</ProductSize>
                                        </Details>
                                        <Removebtn onClick={()=>handleRemove(product._id)}>Remove</Removebtn>
                                    </ProductDetail>
                                    <PriceDetail>
                                        <Hr/>
                                        <ProductAmountContainer>
                                            <Remove/>
                                            <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                                            <Add/>
                                        </ProductAmountContainer>
                                        <ProductPrice>
                                            ₹ {product.price*product.quantity}
                                        </ProductPrice>
                                    </PriceDetail>
                                </Product>
                            ))}
                                    <Hr/>   
                        
                        </Info>)
                        
                        }
                        
                        <Summary>
                        
                            <SummaryTitle>ORDER SUMMARY</SummaryTitle>

                            <SummaryItem>
                                <SummaryItemText>Subtotal: </SummaryItemText>
                                <SummaryItemPrice>₹ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                            </SummaryItem>

                            <SummaryItem>
                                <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping: </SummaryItemText>
                                <SummaryItemPrice>₹ 150.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                            </SummaryItem>
                            
                            <SummaryItem>
                                <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount: </SummaryItemText>
                                <SummaryItemPrice>-₹ 150.90</SummaryItemPrice>
                            </SummaryItem>
                            <Hr/>
                            <SummaryItem type="total">
                                <SummaryItemText >Total: </SummaryItemText>
                                <SummaryItemPrice>₹ {cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
                            </SummaryItem>

                            <StripeCheckout
                                name="Ecofelx"
                                image="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/Ardent10"
                                billingAddress
                                shippingAddress
                                description={`Your total is ₹ ${cart.total}`}
                                currency="INR"
                                amount={cart.total*100}
                                token={onToken}
                                stripeKey={KEY}
                                >
                                <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
                            </StripeCheckout>

                        </Summary>
                    </Bottom>
                </Wrapper>
        

            <Footer/>
        </Container>
    )
```

My Success Page

```
const Success = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    // console.log(location); // to see what state are being passed after placing an order

    const cart = useSelector((state)=>state.cart);
    const data = location.state;
    // console.log(data,cart);

    const currentUser = useSelector((state)=>state.user.currentUser);

    const [orderId, setOrderId] = useState(null);
    console.log(orderId);

    useEffect(() => {
    
        const createOrder = async () => {
            try {
              const res = await userRequest.post("/orders", {
              
                  userId: currentUser._id,
                  products: cart.products.map((item) => ({
                    productId: item._id,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                })),
                amount: cart.total,
                address: data.billing_details.address,
              });
              setOrderId(res.data._id);
            } 
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err);  
          }
        };

        data && createOrder();
      }, [cart, data, currentUser]);


      return (
        <Container>
          {orderId
            ? `Order has been created successfully. Your order number is ${orderId}`
            : `Successfull. Your order is being prepared...`}
          <Link to="/">
            <Button>Go to Homepage</Button>
          </Link>
        </Container>
      );
    };
    
export default Success;
```

stripe in my backend

```
router.post("/payment", (req,res)=>{   
    
    stripe.charges.create(
    {
        source:req.body.tokenId,
        amount:req.body.amount,
        currency:"INR",

    },(stripeErr, stripeRes)=>{
        if(stripeErr){
            res.status(500).json(stripeErr);
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).json(stripeRes);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code snippets doesn't cover how you're tokenizing the card details to charge later. In any case though, you can start off with this guide : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment. If you want to understand how to save a card for later use, you can refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: I have added my success page now which send the accepted order details to my orders route of my backend that eventually gets stored in my MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask Lama Dev directly to get an answer for this, I am also stuck on this issue, cannot find any new guides on stripe integration for MERN projects, all the old ones are using the react-stripe-checkout method.

Check this out though maybe it will help you:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

You can choose which frontend and backend you want to check the code for.

Here is another recent integration: https://codesource.io/how-to-add-credit-card-payment-system-with-stripe-in-react/